# rxdart - using combineLatest, the way combiner works

Tags: dart, stream, rxdart

How does the combiner actually work?

```
Stream<bool> get isValid => Rx.combineLatest2(name1, mobile1, (name2, mobile2) => true);
```

If `name1` and `mobile1` are streams, then what are the types of `name2` and `mobile2` in brackets?

Comment: The types will be `dynamic` because inference doesn't propagate from one argument to another, and the context type doesn't constraint those parameters. What do you mean by "actually work"?

Comment: @lrn I meant what is logic of combineLatest, there are two input streams and how does the resultimg stream produces? What does it mean `=> true`?

Comment: Could you say which part of the ]documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Rx/combineLatest2.html) you have a problem with. I admit it's a little vague, but: Whenever either stream emits a new value (when both have emitted at least one value), the last value emitted by each of the streams is used as argument to the `combine` function, and that function's result is emitted on the returned stream.
In this case, the returned stream emits `true` whenever either stream emits any value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `name2` and `mobile2` refer to the latest content that was emitted by the streams `name1` and `mobile1`. So your question - the types of `name2` and `mobile2` - depend on the streams that you give it.

I think calling them `name1` and `name2` actually kind of makes it a bit confusing, and perhaps it would make more sense to think of it like this:

```
Rx.combineLatest2(nameStream, mobileStream, (name, mobile) => ... )
```

To give a concrete example, imagine that `name` is a `String` and `mobile` is `int`. And imagine that what you want is a Stream of your own class called `Person` which has the parameter `name` and `mobile` like this:

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int mobile;
  
  Person({required this.name, required this.person});
}
```

You could combine your latest `name` and latest `mobile` to get a `Stream<Person>` like this:

```
Stream<Person> get person => 
   Rx.combineLatest2(
      nameStream, mobileStream, (name, mobile) => 
         Person(name: name, mobile: mobile));
```

where:

- `nameStream` is of type `Stream<String>`
- `mobileStream` is of type `Stream<int>`
- `name` is of type `String`
- `mobile` is of type `int`
- and the get function `person` returns `Stream<Person>`

You can specify your class types in the function like this:

```
Stream<Person> get person => 
  Rx.combineLatest2<String, int, Person>(
    nameStream, mobileStream, (name, mobile) => 
       Person(name: name, mobile: mobile));
```